# Why Guid is stored as string and not guid type in azure table storage?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage

I am storing the guid in my azure table storage but the type is 
showing as string and not guid in azure table storage portal.

i am using the rest api with sas token to store the entity in azure table storage .

```
{
  public Guid id {get;set;}
  public string name {get;set;}
}

string sastoke = GetSasToken(); // no issues here
string url = config.table_storage_url + sastoken  // no issues here

// assuming i already have rowkey and partition key 
myClass entity = new myClass{id = Guid.NewGuid();name = "abcdef";}

var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(entity), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
// creating http client
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
   client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
   client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new 
          MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
   HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
   return response;
 }
```

Expected : type of id should be guid in azure table storage portal.

Actual: type of id is showing string in azure table storage portal.

Comment: You're not specifying the OData type for Guid. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/insert-entity)

Comment: Hi @John can you please give an example in the above code please .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use azure table storage rest api for insert data, as per this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/understanding-the-table-service-data-model#property-types):

**By default a property is created as type String, unless you specify a different type.**

And if you want to specify a explicit type, the format should looks like below(doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/insert-entity#json-versions-2013-08-15-and-later)):

[image]

So you need to explicitly specify a type(like `Edm.Guid`) for that property when using rest api. And also note that if you're using SDK, no such issue.

Here is a simple code(maybe there're some better methods for specifying type, but here is just an explanation):

Entity class:

```
public class MyClass
{

    public string PartitionKey { get; set; }
    public string RowKey { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Guid TestId { get; set; }
}
```

The main method:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string url_with_sasToken = "https://xxx.table.core.windows.net/ttt?sasToken";

            MyClass entity = new MyClass
            {
                PartitionKey = "ivan2",
                RowKey = "y1",
                Name = "jack60",
                TestId = Guid.NewGuid()
            };


            //here, I add the odata type for Guid type
            string s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(entity).Replace("}","");
            s += ",\"TestId@odata.type\"" + ":" + "\"Edm.Guid\"}";
            Console.WriteLine(s);

            var content = new StringContent(s, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new
          MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                var t2 = client.PostAsync(url_with_sasToken , content).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                Console.WriteLine(t2.StatusCode);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("completed---");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Then check in azure portal:

[image]